# GetFromItem error for Multimedia type

Tags: component

I am trying to fetch field ID of type Multimedia item from a component link with below code.

```
<img class="bottomMargin" tridion:targetattribute="src" tridion:type="Multimedia" src="@@(GetFromItem(GetURIofComponentLink('global_highlight',0),'Fields.highlight_image'))@@" />
<img class="bottomMargin" tridion:targetattribute="src" tridion:type="Multimedia" src="@@(GetFromItem(GetURIofComponentLink('global_highlight',0),'Fields.highlight_image'))@@" />
```

I am getting the following error.

"An item with the same key has already been added."

Please help !!

Regards,
Gaurav

Comment: GetFromItem and GetUriOfComponentLink look like custom functions. You probably need to look at their source to see the cause.

Comment: GetFromItem is probably from my Get Extension - GetUriOfComponentLink I have no idea. Get wasn't changed in 5 years...

Comment: Did a quick scan of the get source code, I only used a Hashmap when loading attributes within a <a href> tag for some binary processing inside rich text fields - won't be triggered for this code.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Tridion eventlog; expect to see a Templating error event with a stack trace that can provide more clarity where te exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

> **An item with the same key has already been added**

Error indicates that your custom function is trying to insert a value into the dictionary with the same key more than once.